# Regex for getting Everything Between First and Last Instance of Tags

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm working with some Blade Syntax in a project and I need to manually parse the contents of a foreach loop. The syntax effectively looks like:

```
@foreach
  @foreach
    Text
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And I need to find a regex string to grab everything enclosed by the first `@foreach/@endforeach`

I have tried `"@foreach(.*?)@endforeach"`, but this gets caught on the first `@endforeach`.

The intended output for this regex example would be:

```
@foreach
   Text
@endforeach
```

Comment: so all your input strings will have two @foreach and two @endforeach?

Comment: Is the input always indented? What language do you use?

Comment: To JBone: yes, I'm trying to grab the contents and effectively unwrap the contents to an expanded format. To Casimir: Not necessarily, this is within an editor, up to the mercy of the typist, not guaranteed they'll follow convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with (in JavaScript)

```
let str = `@foreach
             @foreach
              Text
            @endforeach
          @endforeach`;
let result = str.match(/^\@foreach[\s\n]+([a-zA-Z0-9@\s\n]+)\@endforeach$/);
console.log(result[1]);//@foreach Text @endforeach
```

`\@foreach[\s\n]+`  => traverse through the first @foreach
  `([a-zA-Z0-9@\s\n]+)`  => grabs everything after it
  `\@endforeach$`   => makesures one @endforeach leaves out

Comment: This is closer, but it's ignoring the inner @foreach/@endforeach, let me update my question to include the intended output.

Comment: Specifically need to grab all of the contents between the outermost @foreach/@endforeach

Comment: I updated my answer. It should get you the desired output

Comment: Wow! This works quite well. Thank you for your explanation as to how the regex works.

Answer (score 1):

this regex does the trick

(?<=@foreach).*(?=@endforeach)

I've created a link to the site where I created it, there you can also generate the code to use this regex in different languages (JavaScript, Java, PHP, Python, and some others)

https://regex101.com/r/9finjx/1

Comment: Although not specified as a requirement in this question, this solution does not work with JS because of the inability to use positive lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

The reason your regex stops at the first `@endforeach` is because the `?` in `.*?` makes it a *lazy* quantifier, meaning the regex will use as few characters as possible. Leaving out the `?` makes it a greedy quantifier, where it will use as many characters as possible.

`@foreach[\s\S]*@endforeach`, making your regex greedy, matches the entire string.

If you want to everything in-between, you may want to use lookahead and lookbehind.

`(?<=@foreach)[\s\S]*(?=@endforeach)` captures everything, including the newline after the first `@foreach`.

However, this will break if there are more `@foreach` loops outside of the first one. e.g.

```
@foreach
    Text
@endforeach
@foreach
    More text
@endforeach
```

Comment: Okay, anything I can do for Lookbehinds not being supported in JS?

Comment: Consider adding javascript to your question's tags.


You could find the first instance of `@foreach` by using `.index('@foreach')`, and get rid of the lookbehind portion of the regex.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, the regex search stops when it finds the first @endforeach.  To get what you want use the {1,} to denotes one or more of that pattern:

```
(@foreach)(.*?)(@endforeach){1,}
```

But in this case, instead of regex, I would recommend you use substr and strpos() and strrpos instead:

```
<?php

$blade_str = "
Some Template content before loop

@foreach
  @foreach
    Some text in loop
  @endforeach
@endforeach

some content after loop";


$loop_str = substr($blade_str, strpos($blade_str , '@foreach'));
print("\nloop_str=" . $loop_str);

// grab start of text after first @foreach
$inner_str = substr($loop_str, 8); // @foreach is 8 chars

// strip out last @endforeach
$inner_str = substr($inner_str, 0, strrpos($inner_str, '@endforeach'));

print("\ninner_str=" . $inner_str);
```

Test this out on http://phptester.net/ you'll get these results:

```
loop_str=@foreach @foreach Some text in loop @endforeach @endforeach some content after loop 
inner_str= @foreach Some text in loop @endforeach
```

Good luck!